# Long Term Package Mirrors

Tags: apt, repository, official-repositories

I am having a bit of a tricky packaging problem with my Trusty Ubuntu cloud machines.  I understand that Trusty is currently in "beta", so I can appreciate that I sort of have to just deal with it.  But there is a wider problem, and I'm looking for a general solution to it.

Basically, an important package (unbound) for my infrastructure got broken by an upgrade.  Since the Ubuntu archives automatically delete old versions of packages (which effectively makes it a rolling release distro, a point for another day...), I am not able to use the basic apt tool to downgrade to the last version.  In particular, what I'd like to do is say:

```
sudo apt-get install unbound=1.4.21-1ubuntu2
```

and have apt-get install that version.  But since it is not in the repositories, the command won't work:

```
$ sudo apt-get install unbound=1.4.21-1ubuntu2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.4.21-1ubuntu2' for 'unbound' was not found
```

I understand I can use dpkg -i to install the package.  But that solution does not work for me -- I'd have to change my hammer to deal with a defective nail.

So, is there any "long-term" repository mirror I can use?  A mirror that methodically keeps at least a few older versions of each package?

Comment: Just report a bug so it gets fixed in the final release. Also, why are you using Beta in production?

Comment: @Braiam: I did report the bug.  And it got fixed.  As to the 'why', Trusty has software that Precise doesn't.  And it's only going to be a beta for a few more weeks.  So I figured I'd design my infrastructure around it and just change images out from under my configuration when Trusty is LTS.  And that's why I was hoping to pin an older version, so that the temporary fix would not be invasive or time consuming.  Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the structure of apt repositories does not allow for multiple versions of a package to be present.  A list of all package mirrors for Ubuntu can be found at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors).  Since Ubuntu inherits from Debian the apt repository system, the description there of [the repository format](https://wiki.debian.org/RepositoryFormat) helps explain how it is set up.  An example of where a directory on the archive may contain multiple versions but for different releases would be in the pool for [xubuntu-docs](http://mirror.it.ubc.ca/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xubuntu-docs/) where there are versions for each separate release but not multiple versions per release.